# Floats and percentage heights and widths in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, height, percentage

I have a fluid mosaic of floating boxes using percentages for width and height.

It works great in Webkit browsers and Firefox, just look at this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mtk57/

I use this technique to specify height from current width: 
http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio

The problem lies with the rows that have different-width blocks, 2 blocks of 30% and 2 blocks of 20%.

**Code for height (20%-width blocks)**

```
.mosaic li::after {
    display:block;
    padding-top:100%;
    content: '';
}
```

**Code for height (30%-width blocks)**

```
.mosaic li::after {
    padding-top:66.6666666666666666666667%;
}
```

In Internet Explorer, the decimals of the height differs slightly, and it seems  to be enough to prevent the block from falling at the beginning of the next row. Internet Explorer doesn't seem to round the pixel values, why?

I think I could put clear:both; using :nth-child, but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: The problem occurs because IE always rounds down when dealing with sub-pixel dimensions.  Given how CSS floats work, this rounding down causes a problem in this case.

The key would be to manually force the height value to be exactly the same for both kinds of tiles.  I am looking for the best way to accomplish that.

Comment: IE doesn't round down the problem occured with heights of respectovely 353.18px and 35.19px. Just one hundredth of a pixel was enough!

Comment: There is still rounding going on, only to 0.01px.  I'm guessing IE rounds down (and so loses 0.01px once in a while), other browsers most likely round to the nearest, and get pixel-perfect fractional layouts in cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to make it work with floats, and I couldn't come up with a satisfactory solution.  However I did find a similar solution with inline blocks that ends up looking exactly the same.  Key points:

a) change `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;` inside `.mosaic li {}`

b) make sure there is no whitespace between `<li>` elements (otherwise there will be horizontal gaps).

c) add `line-height: 0;` to `.mosaic {}` (otherwise there will be vertical gaps).

Resulting js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RN4pj/2/

Comment: I like this solution but my project is almost completed, so changing everything now would be too impacting on what was already done. I used clear:both on the right :nth-child.